# Using Xpath axes to extract preceding element

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from a site with this structure below. I want to extract information in each of the `<li id="entry">`, but both of the entries should also extract the category information from `<li id="category"> / <h2>`

```
<ul class="html-winners">
    <li id="category">
        <h2>Redaktionell Print - Dagstidning</h2>
        <ul>
            <li id="entry">
                <div class="entry-info">
                    <div class="block">
                        <img src="bilder/tumme10/4.jpg" width="110" height="147">
                        <span class="gold">Guld: Svenska Dagbladet</span><br>
                         <strong><strong>Designer:</strong></strong> Anna W Thurfjell och SvD:s medarbetare<br>
                       <strong><strong>Motivering:</strong></strong> "Konsekvent design som är lätt igenkänningsbar. Små förändringar förnyar ständigt och blldmotiven utnyttjas föredömligt."
                    </div>
                </div>
          </li>
          <li  id="entry">
               <div class="entry-info">
                    <div class="block"><img src="bilder/tumme10/3.jpg" width="110" height="147">
                        <span class="silver">Silver: K2 - Kristianstadsbladet</span>
                    </div>
               </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I use a scrapy with the following code:

```
start_urls = [
    "http://www.designpriset.se/vinnare.php?year=2010"
]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = "http://www.designpriset.se/", restrict_xpaths=('//*[@class="html-winners"]')), callback='parse_item'),
)

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@class="entry-info"]'):
        item = ByrauItem()
        annons_list = sel.xpath('//span[@class="gold"]/text()|//span[@class="silver"]/text()').extract()
        byrau_list = sel.xpath('//div/text()').extract()
        kategori_list = sel.xpath('/preceding::h2/text()').extract()
        for x in range(0,len(annons_list)):
            item['Annonsrubrik'] = annons_list[x]
            item['Byrau'] = byrau_list[x]
            item['Kategori'] = kategori_list[x]
            yield item
```

annons_list and byrau_list works perfect, they use xpath to go down the heirarchy from the starting point `//*[@class="entry-info"]`. But kategori_list gives me "IndexError: list index out of range". Am I writing the xpath preceding axe the wrong way?

Comment: You do realize that `//span` will select all `span` elements across the document and `.//span` will limit the `span` selection to those at or beneath the current node, right?

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know! However, in this case the current code stills gives the desired result for annons_list and byrau_list =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [@kjhughes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290085/kjhughes) in comment, you need to add `.` just before `/` or `//` to make your XPath expression relative to current context element. Otherwise the expression will be considered relative to the root document. And that's why the expression `/preceding::h2/text()` returned nothing.

In the case of `/`, you can also remove it from the beginning of your XPath expression as alternative way to make to it relative to current context element :

```
kategori_list = sel.xpath('preceding::h2/text()').extract()
```

Just a note, `preceding::h2` will return all `h2` elements located before the `<div class="entry-info">`. According to the HTML posted, I think the following XPath expression is safer from returning unwanted `h2` elements (false positive) :

```
query = 'parent::li/parent::ul/preceding-sibling::h2/text()'
kategori_list = sel.xpath(query).extract()
```